# django- nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/proxy_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject:11

Tags: python, django, nginx, webserver, gunicorn

I try to deploy a django project with Nginx and Gunicorn with [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04). i did all to-dos but, when i create `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject` file with below code:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name server_domain_or_IP;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/sammy/myproject;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
 }
}
```

and then run `sudo nginx -t` for find errors, i get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/proxy_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject:11
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You're getting the path wrong for `proxy_params` 99% of the time (From my experience), the default location for the `proxy_params` file is `/etc/nginx/proxy_params` but that doesn't seem to be the same for you.

The `proxy_params` file contains the following:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

These parameters are used to forward information to the application that you're proxying to. I've worked with an old `CentOS` server that didn't have a `proxy_params` file, Instead of creating one myself, I just included these parameters directly; and location block looked like this:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
 }
```

So it's up to you. If the file exists in another location just include it with the right location:

`include /path/to/proxy_params`

else you can include the params directly in the location block (Like I did above)

Or create one yourself and place it in `/etc/nginx` (If you want to stick with your current code)

Comment: `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` instead of `proxy_set_header Host $host;` is what I needed. I'm running it in a docker container which runs fine except when I redirect for auth reasons.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a file named `myproject` in the directory `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. But I had no file named  `myproject` in the directory `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. And I do not need that `myproject` file actually, as I didn't create that intentionally.

So I just deleted the `myproject` file from the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory using `sudo rm myproject` and voila! Now `sudo nginx -t` was successful!

Answer (score 1):

When installing nginx on ubuntu, normally, there is `proxy_params` and the path is `/etc/nginx/proxy_params`. But your ubuntu doesn't have it, so making `proxy_params` or adding the code which `proxy_params` has are good solutions as  [danidee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589781/django-nginx-emerg-open-etc-nginx-proxy-params-failed-2-no-such-file#42591098) answered.

This time, I made the docker container which has nginx and `alpine` which is one of the linux distributions. But it doesn't have `proxy_params` same as the `old CentOS` that [danidee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589781/django-nginx-emerg-open-etc-nginx-proxy-params-failed-2-no-such-file#42591098) worked with. So I added the code of `proxy_params` which is the simpler way than making `proxy_params`.

It seems like some linux distributions or some old linux distributions may not have `proxy_params`.

In addition, I've seen [the tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) you use before. For nginx configuration, you better make only one `myproject.conf` at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/myproject.conf`(Don't forget `.conf` after `myproject`. The file without `.conf` cannot be found by nginx). In this case, you don't need to make two files at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject`.