# Why is my nginx reverse proxy not working?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I spent hours figuring this out. Why is my proxy always showing the nginx default page?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

It seems like the server block is never touched. It just goes straight to the default page as if the block wasn't even there. It is linked correctly to sites-enabled, DNS is also setup otherwise I would not see the default page, I restarted nginx, all my regular server blocks are working as excpected.

Comment: Can we also have a look at the `nginx.conf`? And you want to access some domain from your subdomain?

Comment: The example.com was an example. But I figured it out for the weirdest reason. If I did include proxy_params it worked instead of putting them directly it worked. This drove me nuts for hours. But now It works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone in the future. I don't know why but this did the trick:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mysub.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.11:3333;
        include proxy_params;
    }
}
```

I included the proxy_params and added a the listen [::]:80;

This worked on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Nice that you figured it out! Would you mind break it more down for people who have the same problem? Can you try with only the listen line and only the include and have a look if either of that works? Or it needs both? The listen part only changes, that now IPv6 is also listening for port 80 connections. And the include only adds headers to the proxy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589781/django-nginx-emerg-open-etc-nginx-proxy-params-failed-2-no-such-file Kinda weired that this is working now, but maybe you find the correct reason. Might just be the IPv6 support.